# cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' at the time of using session

Tags: asp.net

here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user = Session["Firstname"] as string;
    Label1.Text = "welcome" + (user != null) ? user : "Guest";


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that `"welcome" + (user != null)` is used as the condition in the ternary operator (`? :`). Assuming that you want `Label1.Text` to be `"welcome"` plus the username or `"Guest"` you should move your brackets:

```
Label1.Text = "welcome" + (user != null ? user : "Guest");
```

Comment: @user3655325 is `user` null or is it an empty string? If an empty string then you would need to use `IsNullOrEmpty` instead of a `null` comparison - as suggested in other answers

Answer (score 1):

Try using the null coalescing operator instead, like this:

```
Label1.Text = "welcome" + user ?? "Guest";
```

Alternatively, if you want to explicitly check for null value of the string, you may use the `IsNullOrEmpty` method, like so:

```
Label1.Text = "welcome" + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user) ? user : "Guest");
```

Comment: @AnthonyChu My mistake, forgot to enclose it in parentheses. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Label1.Text = "welcome" + (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))) ? user : "Guest";
```

Comment: This will give the same compiler error. See Smirkin Gherkin's answer.